# Ruby on Rails: has_and_belongs_to_many connection to inherited subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, many-to-many

I am trying to connect two classes (conversation and user) by a many-to-many relationship in Ruby on Rails. I set them both up and added a connection table called conversations_custom_users to connect them and it was working. Once we needed our User model to inherit from another User model, setting conversations in a user object was failing and looking for a connection table with the parent class.

My classes and the conversation migration looks like below (I haven't modified the User migration for the many-to-many relationship):

```
class CustomUser < Spree::User
   serialize :resources, Array
   has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :conversation_ids, class_name: 'Conversation'
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :receiver, :foreign_key => :receiver_id, class_name: 'CustomUser'
end

class CreateConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
   def change
      create_table :conversations do |t|
         t.timestamps
      end

      create_table :conversations_custom_users, id: false do |t|
         t.belongs_to :conversation, foreign_key: 'conversation_id', index: true
         t.belongs_to :custom_user, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', index: true
       end
    end
end
```

I think I shouldn't need to add another table called conversations_spree_users, but I also tried adding one. It didn't solve the problem since then Rails was looking for a spree_user_id field. I also tried adding the spree_user_id field to the conversations_spree_users table, but it wouldn't migrate because it was a duplicate column name!

I think I'm missing something about many-to-many relations or inheritance or both in Ruby. If someone can help with this issue I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You have many options to setup your associations, you can even set the name of the table you want to use if it's not standard, you should be able to configure your association using the options listed here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#join-table

Comment: Thank you, specifying the association table name helped!

Answer (score 0):

you could use [polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to build many-to-many association, the benefit of this approach is that you can use only one join-table for all user's hierarchy inheritance.

```rb
class CreateConversationals < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
 def change
  create_table :conversationals do |t|
   # ...
   t.references :contributor, polymorphic: true, null: false
   t.integer :conversation_id
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class Conversational < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contributor, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :conversationals, :foreign_key => :conversation_id
 has_many :custom_users, :through => :conversationals, :source => :contributor, :source_type => 'CustomUser'
 has_many :other_users, :through => :conversationals, :source => :contributor, :source_type => 'OtherUser'
end

class CustomUser < Spree::User
 has_many :conversationals, as: :contributor
 has_many :conversations, :through => :conversationals, :as => :contributor
end

# i assume you use STI
class OtherUser < CustomUser
end
```

then

```rb
user1 = CustomUser.create(...)
user2 = OtherUser.create(...)
conversation = Conversation.create(...)
conversational1 = Conversational.create(..., conversation_id: conversation.id, contributor: user1)
conversation1 = Conversational.create(...,  conversation_id: conversation.id, contributor: user2)

# many-to-many
user1.conversations
user2.conversations
conversation.custom_users
conversation.other_users
```

Comment: This didn't work for many-to-many relations, but it would work for one-to-many I think.

Comment: @Nikign, i updated my answer, still use `polymorphic association` to build many-to-many relations, the benefit of this approach is that you can use only one `join-table` for all user's hierarchy inheritance.

Comment: So do we need to mention both the main table (CustomUser) and the connection table (Conversational) in the model? Even though CustomUser is included in the Conversational model? To be more clear, each model needs to include two many-to-many relations to maintain one?

Comment: @Nikign i still not understand what you mean. Anyway, it's up to you, beside that, `polymorphic` also has drawback that when the join-table grow up, the query (by polymorphic type) will slow than if there's multiple tables, each one for each type. so single table or multiple tables , your choice.